# C++ Comparing elements of 2 different vectors

Tags: c++, vector, operators

This is my code :

```
// vector 2, vector 3 contain each 7 integers and vector 1 contains 7 vectors of 7 integers.

std::vector < std::vector<int> > vector1;
vector1.push_back(vector2);
vector1.push_back(vector3);

if(vector1[1][0] == vector1[0][0]) {
    std::cout<<"Equal";
}
```

My compiler crashes because of the comparison of the 2 vectors. I have a feeling there is a different way to compare multi-vectors. I've been searching online and cant find something.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Your **compiler crashes**? What do you mean?

Comment: `vector1.push_back(10);` is invalid and should not compile. `vector1` cannot store an `int`. You need to `push_back` a `vector` This smells of an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though. What is your overall goal?

Comment: I am trying to verify if the element of the first vector is equal to the element of the second vector. I edited the code.

Comment: Can you show us the full code? I can't spot any problem with that code..

Answer (score 0):

This code does exactly what you are saying that doesn't work.
If you have created the vector < vector < int > > the proper way, there isn't anything wrong with this code. You are just comparing two number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::vector;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v1{1,2};
    vector<int> v2{2,3};
    vector<vector<int> > v3;
    v3.push_back(v1);
    v3.push_back(v2);
    if(v3[0][0] == v3[1][0])
    {
        cout << "The first elements of the first and second vector of v3 are equal" << std::endl;
    }
    else
       cout << "They are different" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```